# Programatically detect the completion of update of an app from play store

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to programatically detect the completion of an update of an app from the play store; say, using a `BroadcastReceiver`, or anything for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a receiver (in your Androidmanifest.xml or programmatically) with the action ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED. Here others "Action package" that can be usefull : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Hope it helps.